# ui-router on clicking a button $state.go new page

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

http://plnkr.co/edit/D89QGLbKWbqp6T7Igfhy

the above plnkr have my same project of what i have done to navigate to another page on clicking a button(login) i should go to view.html page i am not sure where i am strugling please let me know if you find my error

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: 'templates/view.html',

            });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('view.html');
 });
```

this what my .config file look like

Comment: http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/CbBsA

Comment: can you please provide me in plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/pflylzTsiYo3XitmE1zK?p=preview) you can see `ng-click` directive in the button that call a function in `Login` controller. This function calls `$state.go("login")` that will redirect to `view.html`.

Comment: i am getting error like ionic.bundle.js:23826 GET http://localhost:8100/templates/view.html 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

You need to map your button with the wanted state:

```
<a ui-sref="login">
   <button class="button button-block button-positive">
        login
   </button>
</a>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/J9MmnPac2GXgqL522oHe

Comment: i have ng-click for my button to navigate to view.html

Comment: you link bad plunker

Comment: i am new to plunker sorry for the issues on clicking to the button i should take to new page

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            title: 'UnPublished',
            templateUrl: helper.basepath('templates/view.html'),
            resolve: helper.resolveFor('ui-router')
        })
```